How to Append a new element to a global variable in JavaScript?
Well, i am working in this project in JavaScript, and understanding how the DOM works to operate html from js. The thing is,(the code below)
const templesElement='';
 
 
const displayTemples = (temples)=>{ 
    const templesDiv = document.getElementById("temples");
    templesDiv.innerHTML="<ol>";

    temples.forEach((element) => {
        templesDiv.innerHTML += `<li>${element.templeName} 

        </li>`;
        let article = document.createElement('article');
        let heading3 = document.createElement('h3');

       heading3.innerHTML = element.templeName;

        
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        
        
        img.src = "https://content.churchofjesuschrist.org/templesldsorg/bc/Temples/photo-galleries/";
        img.alt =element.location;

        article.appendChild(heading3);
        article.appendChild(img);
        
        templesElement.appendChild(article);

    });

    
    temples.innerHTML  = "</ol>";
    
}

I have this part of the code that is hard to understand, i am iterating trough an array and want to create elements (like in html) but not touching the code in html, only using js.
the last part of the code
[templesElement.appendChild(article)] is producing errors, first it says that templesElement.appendChild is not a function,but when i looked in W3schools (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) i found that the syntax is correct to append the new element.
My question is, why is it showing error?
Note
templesElement is an empty global variable
Is there another way to create elements and append in DOM??

"templesElement is an empty global variable" - Define an "empty global variable".  If it's just an empty object or single value then appendChild indeed is not a function on that.  templesElement would have to be an element of some kind in the DOM.  Can you expand this to a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem and indicate what you're expecting it to do and why?

const templesElement='';
The previous syntax is the upper part of the code...

Then what you have is a string, not a DOM element.  And there indeed is no function called appendChild on a string.  Should that value be a string?  Did you mean to somehow convert your elements to strings and concatenate them onto that string?  If the intended result is a string, why dynamically build elements just to convert them to strings later?  Why not just directly concatenate string values?

I am creating new html elements trough JavaScript. the article, heading and img.
after i want to append  the heading and the img to the article
lastly append the article to the global variable templesElement....

Yes it did. It solved, now i want to understand, can you give a link where i can read more??

According to a comment on the question, templesElement is:
const templesElement='';

That's not an element, it's a string.  And there indeed is no function called appendChild on strings.
If you just want a string then you may find it easier to just build strings instead of working with elements and then later converting them to strings.  But you could also just convert them to strings by reading their outerHTML property.
For example:
templesElement += article.outerHTML;

Note that this re-assigns to templesElement, so you'd need to change its declaration from const to let.

Alternatively, if you do want the result to be an element then don't declare it as a string, make it an element.  For example:
const templesElement = document.createElement('div');

Then you'd be able to use appendChild on that element.
